# PyQt: Mouse events in QGraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I would like to write a simple program in Python with PyQt.

I have a QGraphicsScene and I would like to do the following:
There are 2 options using two RadioButtons:

1. For generating points. This way if someone clicks on the scene an ellipse will appear.
2. For selecting points.  This way if someone clicks on a point the selected point will be returned.

I'm kinda new at PyQt and also at GUI programming. My main problem is that I don't really understand how mouse events work in Qt.
If someone was so kind and patient to explain me the basics of mouse events and gave me some tipps for the problem explained above, I would be very grateful.

I attach a picture too, to visualize the problem.
[image: GUI]

I was trying to do the problem. For placing the widgets I used the Qt Designer, and then created a subclass called SimpleWindow.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene
import points

class SimpleWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, points.Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SimpleWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.graphicsView.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.graphicsView.scene)
        self.graphicsView.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        self.graphicsView.mousePressEvent = self.pixelSelect


    def pixelSelect(self, event):
        pen = QPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        brush = QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)

        x = event.x()
        y = event.y()

        if self.radioButton.isChecked():
            print(x, y)
            self.graphicsView.scene.addEllipse(x, y, 4, 4, pen, brush)

       if self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
            print(x, y)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = SimpleWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

This is the class generated by the Designer:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(538, 269)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Dialog)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 10, 371, 221))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 82, 31))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Generate"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select"))
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is the meaning of  *the selected point will be returned*?

Comment: Displaying its coordinates is enough.

Comment: I recommend that you try to solve it and tell us the problems you had when you tried. On this subject there is a lot of information on the internet and right here in SO.

Comment: I edited the post. Placed the code there. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Seriously great explain that is what did not work, I also recommend using QGraphicsScene since it returns the position regarding the scene and that is the one that you must use in the items.

Comment: Yes! I forgot to write back. Sorry :) Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Of course. It was my first question here. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a `QGraphicsView` a `QGraphicsScene` is added, each one manages a system of different coordinates. the `QGraphicsView` is similar to a camera and a `QGraphicsScene` is similar to the world, when one adds an item to the scene it must be in its coordinate system.

As you want to add items when you click, it is better to overwrite the `mousePressEvent` method of `QGraphicsScene`, and get the position in the coordinates of the scene for which the `scenePos()` method is used.

Another thing to do is to initialize the attribute `setSceneRect()` which is the space that `QGraphicsView` can see.

A recommendation if several buttons are used use a `QButtonGroup` that maps the buttons making easy the easy handling of the signals.

```
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setSceneRect(-100, -100, 200, 200)
        self.opt = ""

    def setOption(self, opt):
        self.opt = opt

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pen = QPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        brush = QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        x = event.scenePos().x()
        y = event.scenePos().y()
        if self.opt == "Generate":
            self.addEllipse(x, y, 4, 4, pen, brush)
        elif self.opt == "Select":
            print(x, y)


class SimpleWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, points.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SimpleWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.scene = GraphicsScene(self)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.graphicsView.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        group = QButtonGroup(self)
        group.addButton(self.radioButton)
        group.addButton(self.radioButton_2)

        group.buttonClicked.connect(lambda btn: self.scene.setOption(btn.text()))
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.scene.setOption(self.radioButton.text())
```